# Adding images to JSfiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

Does anyone know how to add images to JSfiddle?

I need some help with a problem I'm having but I need to use JSfiddle so that I can show what I have done and hopefully get some help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot link your `LOCAL` image to a website, first upload your image to some image uploading service and than use the path in your jsfiddle

Example

Upload your image to some image uploading service for example [postimage](http://www.postimage.org/)

After uploading your image, copy paste the url in your jsfiddle and it will work...

## [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yes i have mentioned source here. Should i need to remove answer here?

Comment: Yes that's why I removed my comment as well, and nope, you can keep it, but rather closing as a duplicate will make much sense here :)