# Image not displaying in div

Tags: css, html

Im trying to get an background image displayed in a button div but its not showing up.

Changing background-image to background-color works and it displays a color in the correct spot the image should of been.

Im drawing a blank here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6AnC/13/)

This is the piece of code:

```
.strawberry {
height:65px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('src/bg_button.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:center; 
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Im new to html5 so please be gentle.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are not in the correct folder try this:

```
.strawberry {
    height: 65px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("../src/bg_button.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Confirm, code works fine when I plug an image URL in.

Comment: great :), it was just over top of my head

Answer (score 0):

In a jsfiddle, an image referenced that way will need to be gotten from somewhere on the web. When I load your fiddle in Chrome, I get 404 not found errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)   http://fiddle.jshell.net/m6AnC/13/show/src/bg.png
>     http://fiddle.jshell.net/m6AnC/13/show/src/header.jpg
>     http://fiddle.jshell.net/m6AnC/13/show/src/bg_button.jpg

See: [Adding images in JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle)