# How to use image from local system on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

```
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/76kStDSv/food-Wallpaper.png" height="200" width="600"/>
<div id="heading">
      FIND The best Restaurants
</div>
<div>
<select id="location">
    <option>Delhi</option>
    <option>Mumbai</option>
    <option>Chandigarh</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Instead of using the online image in the above code, how can I use the image from local system?

Comment: It does not seem possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it because jsfiddle.net is a web application. It cannot access data from your computer without permission, but there is no option to give it permission. (although you may try using base64 encoding).