# Uploading image on JS fiddle

Tags: html, image, jsfiddle

I was wondering how I could upload a picture on js fiddle in one of my divs.

I tried to save an image to my files and  i tried to pull the image from my files yet my code could not recognize the file name.

Comment: Perhaps some of these earlier comments might help:
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps some of these earlier comments might help (one person clarifies how to load your own images at JSF):
[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172762/adding-images-in-jsfiddle)

[JSfiddle Docs](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/)

Some other external image services examples (there are plenty out there):
[Placeholder.com](https://placeholder.com/)
[Unsplash via their free images](https://unsplash.com)

Another possible way to upload your images is via PostImage which will host it free there, then you can link it onto your web page.
[PostImage](https://postimages.org)